# Livecode "send" with argument that has quotes

Tags: arguments, livecode, quote

I want to do this:

```
Send "MenuPick " & quote & ShortForm & quote to stack "Abbrevs"
```

The stack "Abbrevs" has a handler `MenuPick` that does the usual menu-picking thing. This works fine except for a `ShortForm` argument that has an embedded quote.

How can I send an argument with an embedded double-quote?

These don't work:

- Quoting the string again
- Changing the quote to two quotes
- Escaping the quote with a backslash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I struggled with this some more and found that the arg can be evaluated during the `Send` like this:

```
Put "Send " & quote & "MenuPick ShortForm" \
        & quote & " to stack " & quote & "Abbrevs" \
        & quote into MyCmd
Do MyCmd
```

Comment: What you have done here is create the statement `send "MenuPick ShortForm" to stack "Abbrevs"` inside the variable `MyCmd`, then used the `do` command to execute the statement in the variable. It's an unnecessary step requiring extra processing overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to send the literal string "ShortForm", with quotes, as a parameter with the message, try putting the quoted string into a variable first.

```
put quote & "ShortForm" & quote into tPick
send "menuPick tPick" to stack "Abbrevs"
```

Comment: Nope, I wanted to send the contents of the variable named ShortForm, which include a quote.

Comment: Assuming thevariable `shortForm` contains your quotes, `send "menuPick ShortForm" to stack "Abbrevs"` should work for you.